# Creating Runnable From outer class

Tags: java, runnable

I'm trying to create several tasks which will each call the route on several of the Routers. I'm trying to break up the main list (ArrayList) of routers into sublists which each thread can iterate over.

Does this way of passing variables to the threads cause issues? Or is it something else.

`nbTasks` = number of Runnables

`routersPerThread` = number of routers each thread should call route() on

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbTasks; i++) {
    final List<Router> routerList = 
            routers.subList(i * routersPerThread, (i + 1) * routersPerThread);

    service.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Router r : routerList) {
                r.route();
            }
            sem.release();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not use a fixed-sized thread pool and submit all these tasks (and let it manage the queue)?

Answer (score 2):

You will run into problems when the list changes while a thread is still running. This doesn't happen in the code you show so for this bit you should be fine; eg if you create the list in the constructor and never change it.

The `sem` variable use looks dodgy. You release but never acquire it (assuming it's a semaphore).